# Canvas Context Doesn't Enter Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, fullscreen

I'm messing around with fullscreen APIs. I've learned how to make the Canvas element fullscreen. However, the 2d context is still bordered (top where the browser tabs would be, bottom where my Windows taskbar would be, and sides if the browser wasn't maximized).

For example, I animate a circle that moves to the top of the canvas. If the canvas is fullscreen, it consideres the top of the canvas to be somewhere about a 10th of the way below the top of my monitor.

How can I fix this?

CSS:

```
canvas {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000000;
}
```

JS:

```
function doStartup(event) {
    document.fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || 
    document.mozFullscreenElement
          || document.msFullscreenElement || 
    document.webkitFullscreenDocument;
    document.exitFullscreen = document.exitFullscreen || 
    document.mozExitFullscreen
          || document.msExitFullscreen || document.webkitExitFullscreen;

    update();
}

function toggleFullscreen() {
    let elem = document.querySelector("canvas");
    elem.requestFullscreen = elem.requestFullscreen || 
    elem.mozRequestFullscreen
        || elem.msRequestFullscreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen;

    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
        elem.requestFullscreen().then({}).catch(err => {
            alert(`Error attempting to enable full-screen mode: 
        ${err.message} (${err.name})`);
        });
    } 
    else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have functions to figure out the mouse position and draw that on the screen. The mouse position works fine in both non-fullscreen and fullscreen modes. However, when I enter fullscreen, the position is drawn lower on the canvas than it is supposed to.

Comment: That's probably a bug in your functions for the mouse positions, not in the functions that handle toggling fullscreen.

Comment: @vrugtehagel no because I've tried drawing other things -- lines, shapes, animations, etc. It all cuts off before the top of the fullscreen canvas.

Comment: Perhaps an issue with the size of your canvas? It should be properly resized when you resize the window, otherwise it'll be stretched. I'm positive the bug is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Note: your check for `document.fullscreenElement` will only work in browsers that do natively support this property, your polyfill won't work, since you'll just assign a value to this property, but not the getter that gets called. Now, your question is very unclear. What are you trying to do and what doesn't work? What does "bordered" means here?

Comment: @Kaiido in this case, "bordered" means dead space of the fullscreen canvas. The canvas is there, but I cannot draw anything in that space. It's usually the top and bottom of my screen, where the browser tabs and Windows taskbar would be. Also, if my browser is small, the "border" or dead space appears on the sides as well when the canvas becomes fullscreen.